# Why does the word "casino" break my form?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

Here's one that might get you scratching your heads - it certainly has me!

I'm using a form to submit content to WordPress' 'update_post_meta' function.

The form itself is pretty simple, just a range of input and textarea fields. On submit the action directs to the same page where some PHP takes over to do validation on the `$_POST` info before submitting to Wordpress. Now it all works perfectly, except one very strange bug:

Whenever you use the word 'casino' in any of the fields, instead of submitting the form, the page refreshes and throws up a `404 error`, even though the address bar shows a perfectly valid URL! I don't believe it's my PHP code as I don't think we get that far in the process, so I'm thinking it's a server thing, but I can't imagine why. This happens on any form across the whole site and I've also got the same result on other sites hosted with the same hosting company (Namecheap, FYI).

So, the question is, can anyone suggest a reason why sending that word in particular to `$_POST` would break a form and cause that error?

PS. I'm currently solving this using a `replace()` javascript function so 'casino' never gets sent with the form, but if the 'casion' issue can solved I would be very grateful. It would at least stop me puzzling over it.

Comment: Sounds like a spam protection mechanism, maybe on Wordpress level, maybe on server level

Comment: Are you able to manually insert the word into the database? or are you able to see if the word posts directly to it?  This could narrow down your problem?

Comment: Contact your web host. They probably have an overaggressive `mod_security` rule which is causing this behavior.

Comment: Nemecheap do have very zealous security settings, I got IP banned the other day for changing my password! I'll send an email and see what they say. I can insert the word into WordPress via other methods, it's only the $_POST stage that causing it problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the probability of being recognized as spam is high.
Casinos should be used well because there are many websites that cannot be used by the word itself.
Using the language of other countries is one of the ways to promote it by openly saying "[우리카지노][1]" like me.
I hope you will answer your question.